# Matlab - How to obtain values of pixels?

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

If I have an image, how can I obtain the values of each pixel in that image using `matlab`

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Images are matrices (2D if grayscale, 3D if colored) in MATLAB.

You can use `x(i,j)` to access a pixel at location `(i,j)` in a grayscale image.

If the image is colored, you can use `x(i,j,:)` to access the r, g, b values in a 3-vector, respectively. If you need individual channels, then, you can use `x(i,j,1)` for red for example.

You may read [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I retrieve the image indices? As when I used the following command: `p1=I(0,0);`, I got:
`??? Attempted to access I(0,0); index must be a positive integer or
logical.`

Comment: The indices start from 1 and goes to the length of the dimension. It is not like in C.

Comment: Got what you mean. But, isn't there some more practical way to get `all` the pixel values without going index by index? Especially as you know some times you may have an image with a large number of pixels, and would be very time consuming accessing each pixel individually. What do you think? Thanks

Comment: That is the slicing operator `:`. See http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html

Comment: Literally had a computer vision professor who never taught us a single bit of code  with Matlab.  Thank you for this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape` to extract all the pixel values of the image into a vector with pixel values:

```
frame = imread('picture.jpg');
frame_size = size(frame);
allpixels = reshape(frame, frame_size(1)*frame_size(2), frame_size(3))
```

This can be useful when you want to vectorize your Matlab code (to avoid a `for` loop that goes through every pixel). To get back the original image representation:

```
frame2 = reshape(allpixels, frame_size);
```

Comment: How to transform coordinates of the "query" to pixels? E.g., I want to know the values at pixels (1,1) and (20,20). How do I write it?

Answer (score 0):

to get the values at `pixel(1,1)` we simply write `image(1,1)`.